# Confused about _.memoize() implementation

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js

I'm learning different implementations of the memoize function, and something is confusing me. Here is one version of the code:

```
_.memoize = function(func) {
    let cache = {};

    return function() {
      let arg = JSON.stringify(arguments); //arg is an stringified array
      if(!(arg in cache)) {
        cache[arg] = func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      return cache[arg];
    };
  };
```

My understanding of `cahce[arg]` is that the `cache` object has a key of `arg`, or if it doesn't, the function call of `func.apply(this, arguments)` becomes the property at an `arg` key. If `arg` is already a key in `cache`, than the function returns the property at `cache[arg]`.

Ok, but isn't `arg` an array with a string in it? Assigned to a stringified version of `arguments`? Or is it a super long, single string formed by `JSON.stringify`?

How are the different arguments accessed? To me, this seems like the `cache` has a single key of either an array or a long string. Which means the identity of the individual arguments would be lost in a single piece of data, and I don't see how they are being accessed. I guess I would assume a for loop or forEach would loop through to access each argument, but that's not happening, so I don't really know how to read this.

Comment: `arg` is the return value of [`JSON.stringify`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) of [`arguments`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). `JSON.stringify` will never return an Array. Object keys are never Arrays. Have you tried simply inserting a `console.log(arg);` into this code?

Answer (score 2):

> Ok, but isn't arg an array with a string in it?

No, it is actually:

> Or is it a super long, single string formed by `JSON.stringify`?

Yes. For example, if you memoize a function and then call it with

```
foo(1, 2)
foo(3, 4, 5)
foo('str')
```

the cache keys will then be composed of the following strings:

```
{"0":1,"1":2}
{"0":3,"1":4,"2":5}
{"0":"str"}
```

Each such line uniquely identifies a particular combination of arguments; there is a **one-to-one mapping** between a unique ordered number of arguments and the resulting stringified key. No information is lost; the fact that the arguments can be converted into a single string representing those arguments does not mean that any information about the arguments (their order or value) goes away; it's just put into a different format, that of a string, for the cache to work. (One-to-one correspondence is an [incredibly useful technique in mathematics and algorithms. This is just one instance of it.](https://science.jrank.org/pages/4861/One-One-Correspondence.html))

> I guess I would assume a for loop or forEach would loop through to access each argument, but that's not happening

That loop *is* happening, it's just implemented in native code, under the hood with `JSON.stringify`. But it only has to be done one way. Once an ordered set of arguments has been turned into a string, that string can then be used to uniquely identify the arguments, so the key can then be either looked up on the cache, or set on the cache.

```js
function foo() {
  console.dir(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}
foo(1, 2);
```